# DetailsView Error: "Must declare the scalar value..."

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to use DetailsView in ASP.NET and c# to show a list of students that are associated with the logged-in user (which will be a teacher after they login to the system). I have been trying to using scalar values so my program can be more dynamic once a teacher types in the last name of the student they want to find in the system. I'm not sure why I am getting the error
`must declare the scalar value`
when I (think I) am declaring it on the ASP side of my code. I've been searching for solutions to this for a couple of hours now so any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:Table runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUserBlank" runat="server" Text="joeB" ></asp:Label>
                
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btSearch_Click" Text="Search" />
                <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="LastName"
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="StudentID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="StudentID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TShirt_Size" HeaderText="TShirt_Size" SortExpression="TShirt_Size" />
                    </Fields>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        No Student found
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                </asp:DetailsView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource
                    runat="server"
                    ID="SqlDataSource1"
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Lab3 %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT Student.StudentID, Student.LastName, Student.FirstName, Student.Age, Student.TShirt_Size FROM Student INNER JOIN Teacher ON Student.TeacherID = Teacher.TeacherID WHERE Teacher.Username = @Username AND Student.LastName = @LastName">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="@LastName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblUserBlank" Name="@Username" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

    </asp:Table>

</asp:Content>
```

c# code behind:

```
 protected void btSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="@LastName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblUserBlank" Name="@Username" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
```

for this (remove the `@` char from the `Name` flag value):

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="LastName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblUserBlank" Name="Username" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't see the issue earlier, as it would have saved me so much time. I appreciate the help.